# How to change the language at runtime on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to use a language change button, I'm using the following:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["de"], forKey: 
"AppleLanguages") NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

But it only works when the application is restarted.

**How I can change the language at runtime?**

Answer (score 0):

**IN SWIFT 3**

**1. Download "NSBundle+Language" .h .m classes from here** 
https://gist.github.com/narikbi/352e93e446e8b1faf283

**2. #import "NSBundle+Language.h"** in to **Objective-c bridging Header file** for swift use

**3. Put this global method in to your "Appdelegate.swift":-**

```
//MARK:- Language Setter 
public func changeLanguage(){

    if   var arr = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? [String]){
        let changedKey  =  arr[0] == "ja" ? "en":"ja"

        //this will set current language key for future use
        UserDefaults.standard.set([changedKey], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        //Run time  conversion if you want
        Bundle.setLanguage(changedKey)//Magic Line ;)
    }

}
```

**4. Use any where in your controller with UIButton or Switch toggle Action :-**

```
 @IBAction func btnSwitchTaped(_ sender: Any) {

    print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") ?? "")
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).changeLanguage()

   //if you want to check your string programatically on console print when  switch toggle value(testing purpose)
    let check  =  NSLocalizedString("Test", comment: "testing")
    print(check)

}
```

**Happy coding :)**